# Which factory design pattern i should use?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

Currently i got an entity class:

```
public class Notification {

   private NotificationType type;
   private LocalDateTime sentDate;
   private String message;
   private String imageUrl;
   private String refId;
}
```

And an enum:

```
public enum NotificationType {

   INVITATION_TO_GROUP("INVITATION_TO_GROUP"),
   LEAVING_GROUP("LEAVING_GROUP"),
   QUESTION_ANSWERED("QUESTION_ANSWERED"),
   NEW_OWNER("NEW_OWNER");

   private String value;

   NotificationType(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   @JsonValue
   public String getValue() {
       return value;
   }
}
```

I want to create notifications based on enum value so i created a simple method in my notification service:

```
public <T> Notification createNotification(NotificationType type, T obj) {

   Notification response = null;
   GroupRequest request;

   switch(type) {
       case INVITATION_TO_GROUP:
           request = ((GroupRequest) obj);
           response =  new Notification(
               NotificationType.INVITATION_TO_GROUP,
               ...
               request.getId().getUser()
           );
           break;
       case LEAVING_GROUP:
           request = ((GroupRequest) obj);
           response = new Notification(
               NotificationType.LEAVING_GROUP,
               ...
               request.getId().getGroup().getOwner()
           );
           break;
       case NEW_OWNER:
           Group group = ((Group) obj);
           response = new Notification(
               NotificationType.NEW_OWNER,
               ...
               group.getOwner()
           );
           break;
       case QUESTION_ANSWERED:
          //??
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }

   return response;
}
```

As you can see i got one generic parameter for diffrent objects that i use to initialize Notification objects. It works for first 3 enum values but for *QUESTION_ANSWERED* value besides passing an object like in previous 3 cases i need to pass also a String value and the whole method would look even more ugly than now. I think i need to use Factory desing pattern but i really can't fit which one to use for diffrent number of parameters. Do i need to create simple factory interface with methods like *createNotificationForInvitation*, *createNotificationForQuestionAnswered* etc. for each enum value with diffrent parameters and all of them will return *Notification* objects? How to make it look more pretty? :)

Comment: You're using generics badly. You should not be having to cast `obj` to the correct class. You probably want to use [*method overloading*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: Ok so i can remove `createNotification` method from notification service and then i should create an interface with 4 methods for each enum value that takes specific `obj` types? Also for this interface an implementation that would basicly do the same returning `Notification` objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factory in Java when concrete objects take different constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885836/factory-in-java-when-concrete-objects-take-different-constructor-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I am skeptical on whether Factory pattern is good choice here, since besides the type you switch on, you also pass a bunch of varying parameters for each type. It shows when having to cast the request type, set parameters and pass in the constructor for each case.

I would suggest polymorphism and as Michael suggested overload your constructor.

Let's say you have a base class BaseRequest and then subclasses such as InvitationRequest, NewOwnerRequest, etc.

Then your Notification class would look like:

```
public class Notification {

    public Notification(InvitationRequest request) { 
        //your setting up here 
    }

    public Notification(NewOwnerRequest request) {
       ... 
    }

    public Notification(QuestionAnswered request) {
        //QuestionAnswered has the String value you wanted 
    }

}
```